# Conjoint Packages for R

Tags: r, conjoint-analysis

Could you recommend an easy to use or comprehensive conjoint analysis package for R?

Comment: not R, but I use biogeme to estimate discrete choice models for transportation and private sector research: http://biogeme.epfl.ch/. Be glad to give you some tips to get up and running if this is the type of analysis you need to do.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've never used R for conjoint analysis, but here are a couple of things I found when I hunted around.

- Aizaki and Nishimura (2008) have an article "Design and Analysis of Choice Experiments Using R: A brief introduction" ([Free PDF available here](http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/e10/help/att-8876/DCE_with_R.pdf)).

Perhaps check out the following packages:

- [AlgDesign](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/AlgDesign/index.html) for constructing choice sets
- [prefmod](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/prefmod/prefmod.pdf) for analysing paired comparison data
- [conf.design](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/conf.design/conf.design.pdf) for constructing factorial designs

Answer (score 11):

[mlogit](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mlogit/index.html) is the best R package I've found for modelling discrete choice data.  It supports the basic multinomial logit, as well as more advanced models such as multinomial probit and mixed logit.  The package also includes specification tests to choose between different models.

Comment: This is a great answer.  One of the vignettes for the package even goes through and answers a bunch of questions from the Train book.

Answer (score 6):

You may want to use [faisalconjoint](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/faisalconjoint/index.html) package in R, it is tested with many published and research data, it works perfectly, one on important thing its works without design restriction and rank procedure. It works in all condition and provide accurate estimates.

Comment: The most answers and packages are only for traditional conjoint analysis. Are there any packages or methods to do a choice based conjoint? (Example: One choice out of 10 products in round about 5000 purchases) @Faisal Afzal Siddiqui: Choice based is not possible with your method, only traditional ranking or rating data. Correct?

Answer (score 2):

The best in my opinion for R is a conjoint package from CRAN:
http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/conjoint/index.html

Comment: Welcome to the site, @user24799. Would you mind saying a little bit about this package? Why do you think it's the best?

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for models other than logit,

1. you can use 'survival' package to build conditional multinomial
   logit model.
2. you can use 'bayesm' package to build hierarchical
   bayesian(HB) model. Sawtoothsoftware asked the guy who created this
   package to help them build HB model in their software.

Answer (score 2):

Faisal Conjoint Model (FCM) is an integrated model of conjoint
analysis and random utility models, developed by Faisal Afzal Sid-
diqui, Ghulam Hussain, and Mudassir Uddin in 2012. Its algorithm
was written in R statistical language and available in R [29]. Its
design is independent of design structure. It could be used for any
research design i.e. full prole, orthogonal, factorial, supersaturated
etc. Another important point about FCM is rank procedure. It
works for every kind of ranks i.e. unique ranks, percentage ranks,
tight ranks, missing ranks etc. It has been tested for many published
data. Most of the times, FCM results are same with same magnitudes,
often the rank

Comment: Looks like you already answered this before. With another account.

Answer (score 0):

There is a library 'Conjoint' with many features and sample to find utilities.
For a quick preview check the link. This will help you get started.

https://rpubs.com/haj3/conjoint

Answer (score 0):

For R:
"**survival**" (clogit) for multinomial logit (MNL) model.
"**mlogit**" for a wide range of models (MNL, nested logit, heteroscedastic logit, mixed logit (MXL) also known as random parameters logit, ...).
In the same spirit you should take a look at "**Rchoice**" (file:///C:/Users/kruci/Downloads/v74i10.pdf).
"**bayesm**" for bayesian version of MNL/MXL - However if you are interested in bayesian approach I would strongly recommand the great "**RSGHB**" package.
"**gmnl**" for the generalised MNL model.
"**flexmix**" for latent class logit (LCL) model.
More generally it is important to keep in mind that choice models are a special case of multilevel (or hierarchical) models (you have choices nested within participants themselves nested within higher units: supermarkets, countries, etc.) - So everything that can be used for multilevel modelling (e.g., the great "**lme4**" package) and that can also accommodate the discrete nature of the choice variable would do the job. For example, you could use "lme4" if the choices are binary (Do you want this product? Yes/No) or made between 2 options (Which product do you want? A/B).

With Stata, you have many commands useful for choice modelling:
**clogit** for MNL
**mixlogit** for MXL
**clogithet** for heteroscedastic MNL
**lclogit** for latent class logit
**gmnl** for generalised MNL
Many of these commands have been developped/refined by Arne HOLE (Great job!)
http://www.stata.com/meeting/uk13/abstracts/materials/uk13_hole.pdf

Choice modellers also use other software:
nlogit (developped by W. Greene)
biogeme (Thanks to M. Bierlaire) - Great tool but can only be used for choices modelling
I've heard about LatentGOLD but not sure ...

For those who want to use MATLAB, You got to take a look at:
Mikołaj Czajkowski webiste (http://czaj.org/research/estimation-packages/dce)
Kenneth TRAIN website (https://eml.berkeley.edu/~train/software.html) - Actually most of the choice functions come from Kenneth TRAIN's work

Finally, for those who are willing to invest a significant amount of time in the coding of choice models, Chandra BHAT website is amazing (http://www.caee.utexas.edu/prof/bhat/FULL_CODES.htm)

Many thanks to all these great researchers (Train, Bhat, Bierlaire, Hole,  Croissant, Czajkowski, etc) who made this possible!