# Sample session for analysis of conjoint data in R

Tags: r, conjoint-analysis, choice-modeling

While I have successfully used R for Cluster Analysis and Correspondence Analysis, I'm new to the use of R-project for Choice-Based Conjoint.

Per recommendations in [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9283/conjoint-packages-for-r), I'm looking at the following [R] Packages for purposes of analyzing choice-based conjoint data:

- ChoiceModelR
- mlogit
- AlgDesign for constructing choice sets
- prefmod for analysing paired comparison data
- conf.design for constructing factorial designs

For reference purposes, I'm curious whether there is a sample R-project session showing the use of one or more of these packages to:

- Specify attributes and attributes levels
- Analyze choice-based conjoint data to list out respondent-level utility values
- Simulate market share

Has anyone seen a sample R-project session of this nature? Or can someone who has created such a session post it?

Comment: I found a sample session for ChoiceModelR (copied below). Does anyone have a sample session for prefmod?